# Java - Pass a variable from user input to another java file

Tags: java, file, variables

I am new to Java and I have a project to do, so I have a java file and the user have to choose from a listing of files in a directory. The input from user is saved in a variable (fileName). I want to use that variable in another java file for doing some other work. I searched online but didn't find any solution that works for me. Probably I've done something wrong.

code of the first file:

```
public class Director {

private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(source);
    os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    

    // Creates an array in which we will store the names of files and directories
    String[] pathnames;

    // Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
    // into an abstract pathname
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\available_videos");

    // Populates the array with names of files and directories
    pathnames = f.list();
    System.out.println("Files in the directory:");
    // For each pathname in the pathnames array
    for (String pathname : pathnames) {
        // Print the names of files and directories
        System.out.println(pathname);
    }
    
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
    System.out.println("Enter file name");
    String fileName = myObj.nextLine();
    File source = new File("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\available_videos\\" + fileName);
    File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\raw_videos\\" + fileName);
    copyFileUsingStream(source, dest);


}


}
```

code of the second file that i want to use the input:

```
 public class TestFFMpeg {

static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(TestFFMpeg.class);



public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = null;
    FFprobe ffprobe = null;
    

    
    try {
        log.debug("Initialising FFMpegClient");
        ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("C:\\Users\\miltos\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
        ffprobe = new FFprobe("C:\\Users\\miltos\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    log.debug("Creating the transcoding");
    FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
            .setInput("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\raw_videos\\" + filename) //updated
            .addOutput("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\videos\\" + filename) //updated
            .setVideoBitRate(200000) 
            .done();
      log.debug("Creating the executor");
    FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);

    log.debug("Starting the transcoding");
    // Run a one-pass encode
    executor.createJob(builder).run();
    log.debug("Transcoding finished");
}


}
```

Comment: You can create a constructor in class second , where in you can pass the filename as parameter.

Comment: I have question to ask , when you have to pass the filename parameter in class one? could you please specify the position?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I want to pass the filename variable in the input (and output)  of the ffmpeg builder. I saw your code. Where do i put the "TestFFMpeg obj = new TestFFMpeg(filename);" ? above the declaration of the class? And when i put the other code you wrote under the declaration of the class, i get errors about the variable filename

Comment: No,you should write it in class one : TestFFMpeg obj = new TestFFMpeg(filename); because you have the filename in class one right? I think it should be written before copying the files . Before this :     copyFileUsingStream(source, dest);
 I updated the code for the error.

Comment: Thanks! Now i am getting an error in the second class, where i put the variable filename as input and output (i updated the code on these parts) . The error is:cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Comment: Updated the code for the same

Comment: okay i got no erros of compiling now. But there is an error when I am running it that there is not a file like this. But probably I am not doing it right. I just run the first class, and then the second (in eclipse). Am i doing something wrong? Do i need to run them together somehow so the pass of the variable can work?

Comment: I understand the issue , let me update the code and then you can use that . What you should be doing is, create a method in second class and call that from first class.

Comment: okay now they are running together but i receive the same error that there is no file with that name :/

Comment: Where did you add the code in class one? Did you check if there is file in that location ?

Comment: in the first class, i added it at the end, after the copyFileUsingStream(source, dest);
There is the file that user inputs in the raw_videos folder.

Comment: That is the issue, since file is already copied . So it is saying no files available. Place that code above that where copy is happening

Comment: tried it, but still same result. Maybe it takes the filename variable as a folder and not a file?

Comment: Could you please check on that ? You can debug using log in console. If the path is correct or not.

Comment: when i debug i get this: [INFO ] 2020-06-26 19:16:27.198 [main] RunProcessFunction - C:\Users\miltos\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -v error -i C:\Users\miltos\Desktop\polimesa\raw_videos\filename -b:v 200000 C:\Users\miltos\Desktop\polimesa\videos\filename
C:\Users\miltos\Desktop\polimesa\raw_videos\filename: No such file or directory
Though there is the file i want (what the input is) in the directory raw_videos

Comment: I did a small update in the code. Please check

Comment: Okay so that was the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: Atlast the problem is solved, good to know. happy learning. I hope you will not mind upvoting the answer

Comment: i need 15 reputation to upvote and i have just 13 :(

Comment: Now you have it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a variable names filename in class second also, which you will pass from the class one , while creating an object of class second like

```
TestFFMpeg obj = new TestFFMpeg();
obj.methodInSecondClass(filename);
```

Second Class :

```
    public class TestFFMpeg {
    
    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(TestFFMpeg.class);
    
    public void methodInSecondClass(String filename){

    FFmpeg ffmpeg = null;
        FFprobe ffprobe = null;
        
    
        
        try {
            log.debug("Initialising FFMpegClient");
            ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("C:\\Users\\miltos\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
            ffprobe = new FFprobe("C:\\Users\\miltos\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        log.debug("Creating the transcoding");
        FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
                .setInput("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\available_videos\\"+filename) //this is where i want the same variable
                .addOutput("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\videos\\"+filename) //this is where i want the same variable
                .setVideoBitRate(200000) 
                .done();
          log.debug("Creating the executor");
        FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);
    
        log.debug("Starting the transcoding");
        // Run a one-pass encode
        executor.createJob(builder).run();
        log.debug("Transcoding finished");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There is a small update in the code  .setInput("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\available_videos\\"+filename) 
.addOutput("C:\\Users\\miltos\\Desktop\\polimesa\\videos\\"+filename) . Please update that